# Codeigniter function undefined error

Tags: codeigniter

**My custom core Class in application/core/MY_Controller.php**

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller{

    protected $data = array();


    function __construct(){

        parent::__construct();

    }

    function rander_page($view){

        //do this to don't repeate in every controller
        $this->load->view('includes/header');
        $this->load->view('top_menus');
        $this->load->view($view, $this->data);
        $this->load->view('includes/footer');

    }

}
```

**Index Controller in application/controllers**

```
class Index extends MY_Controller{

    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();  
    }

    function index(){

        $this->render_page('index');

    }

}
```

**Error is :Fatal error: Call to undefined method Index::render_page() in D:\wamp\www\ci\application\controllers\index.php on line 10**

i am trying to use one controller for all pages help plz

Comment: why can't you use library instead of modifying / adding code in core folder?

Comment: You have a typo error in your function name in `MY_Controller` it `render_page` not `rander_page`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the error is the clue itself, it has mentioned the function is undefined. You have not defined render_page function. Instead, you misspelled and named it as rander_page().

May be you are trying to write:

```
function render_page()
```

as you have called it like :

```
$this->render_page('index');
```

Answer (score 0):

You have misspelled the function name. Call **$this->rander_page('index');**